# ntpdig/sntp sometimes output "weird" correct time

Tags: ntp

I am trying to get correct estimated time from an ntp server. Every once in a while `ntpdig` returns "weird" output.

```bash
# Weird, it contains 5 or even less digits in a fractional part of the output.
:~$ ntpdig -4 time.google.com
2023-12-18 16:39:36.74198 (+0100) +0.779136 +/- 0.013945 time.google.com 216.239.35.0 s1 no-leap

# Normal, it contains 6 digits in a fractional part of the output, even has trailing zeroes.
:~$ ntpdig -4 time.google.com
2023-12-18 16:40:08.970600 (+0100) +0.779832 +/- 0.014195 time.google.com 216.239.35.12 s1 no-leap
```

Command finished successfully in both cases, i.e. returns 0 exit code.

Command is supposed to output correct synced clock with options as in example above. If I compare its output clock values to the local clock of my machine with the following simple script:

```bash
# script.sh
ntp_output=`ntpdig -4 time.google.com`
t1_ms=`echo "$ntp_output" | cut -c-26 | xargs -i date -d '{}' +%s%3N`
t2_ms=`date '+%s%3N'`
t_diff_ms=$(($t2_ms-$t1_ms))
echo "ntpdig $ntp_output >>> vs local clock: $t_diff_ms ms"
```

Exactly on weird outputs time difference from local clock will "deviate":

```
$ ./script.sh 
ntpdig 2023-12-18 16:57:05.550649 (+0100) +0.773842 +/- 0.013840 time.google.com 216.239.35.0 s1 no-leap >>> clock diff: -685 ms
$ ./script.sh 
ntpdig 2023-12-18 16:57:06.309844 (+0100) +0.774098 +/- 0.006148 time.google.com 216.239.35.8 s1 no-leap >>> clock diff: -687 ms
$ ./script.sh 
ntpdig 2023-12-18 16:57:06.910969 (+0100) +0.774642 +/- 0.013711 time.google.com 216.239.35.12 s1 no-leap >>> clock diff: -688 ms
$ ./script.sh 
ntpdig 2023-12-18 16:57:07.462092 (+0100) +0.775254 +/- 0.006074 time.google.com 216.239.35.4 s1 no-leap >>> clock diff: -684 ms
$ ./script.sh 
ntpdig 2023-12-18 16:57:08.49674 (+0100) +0.772464 +/- 0.017524 time.google.com 216.239.35.0 s1 no-leap >>> clock diff: -1130 ms  <--- where only 5 fractional digits are output estimated correct time is significantly further away from local clock reading
```

Which makes me think that whatever time command outputs in "weird" cases is incorrect.
What is up with these "weird" `ntpdig` outputs? Can they be trusted? I could not find anything about them.

I've bundled ntpdig/sntp since in some distros (Debian 12) sntp is just an alias to ntpdig.

I do not know what to try. :) I would expect ntpdig/sntp to output data in constant format, i.e. with 6 digits in fractional part of the time. And if this is not possible for some reason I would expect command to fail with some error code.

Did anyone ran into anything like that?